# Firebase Auth user is logged out on every page refresh - React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-redux, firebase-authentication

Every time the page is refreshed the user is sent back to the login screen after authentication. I am using the onAuthStateChanged listener, however, after the page is refreshed it acts like there was no authenticated user to begin with.

```
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const currentUser = useSelector((state) => state.user.value);
  useEffect(() => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        dispatch(setCurrentUser({ email: user.email, uid: user.uid }));
        console.log("user", user.email);
      }
    });
  }, []);
  return currentUser.email ? <LoggedIn /> : <Welcome />;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const currentUser = useSelector((state) => state.user.value);
  useEffect(() => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        dispatch(setCurrentUser({ email: user.email, uid: user.uid }));
        console.log("user", user.email);
      }
    });
  }, [currentUser]);
  return currentUser?.email ? <LoggedIn /> : <Welcome />;
}
```

maybe, that would help.
just add currentUser to the second argument array in useeffect

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I know that `onAuthStateChanges()` method is asynchronus. So just move rediraction inside this method.

```js
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const currentUser = useSelector((state) => state.user.value);
  useEffect(() => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        dispatch(setCurrentUser({ email: user.email, uid: user.uid }));
        console.log("user", user.email);
        openRoute(<LoggedIn />)
        return
      }
      openRoute(<Welcome />)
    });
  }, []);
}
```

This function triggers whenever auth state changes so if you log out you wanna back to login page and this way will work.